# ASPx set Cookie Domain

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a code as follows:

```
 this.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("COOKIENAME",'test'));
```

I want to add the domain ".test.com" for this cookie. How do I do so? I tried the standard:

```
    this.Response.Cookies["COOKIENAME"].Domain = ".test.co.uk";
```

But the cookie is not being set for the whole domain. Any suggestions?

The following is not working either:

```
HttpCookie MyCookie = new HttpCookie("COOKIENAME");
        MyCookie.Value = 'test';
        MyCookie.Domain = ".test.co.uk";

        this.Response.Cookies.Add(MyCookie);
```

Comment: Just wanted to add that I am setting this cookie from a sub-domain i.e abc.test.co.uk is setting this cookie. It is working fine on abc. but it is not working on www.

Comment: Based on your code [and this example](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/971108.htm) I can't see anything wrong... (Aside from using single quotes for a string, but that's likely a typo in this post specifically).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need the ".", so just `MyCookie.Domain = "test.co.uk";`.

Comment: That was going to be my next guess, as they [use this example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookie.domain.aspx).

Comment: ".test.co.uk" is a domain wide cookie and is for all subdomains of test.co.uk.

Comment: @Ash Berlin, we know this and that's why he was having a problem. My answer doesn't say anything contrary to your comment, but it is the solution in .NET. Not sure why you would downvote it.

Comment: From what little I could grok of the CookieContainer class (i.e. when doing `req.CookieContainer = ...` it doesn't look like this would work. Does the cookie actually get sent along by just removing the leading '.'?

Comment: @Louis how can we remove . symbol i only want domain name not with .

Comment: @AshBerlin-Taylor have fixed that?

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use the Cookie `Path` property to define the domain of the cookie

Comment: `Path` is for a directory path (e.g. you want it to only work in the `/Portal/` directory) OP is correct, it's `Domain` you want to use.